# How to prevent reading wrong double data C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am reading 5 lines which contain STRING, DOUBLE data.
I am reading the string then deleting the last character which is the comma and then read the double. (in is an ifstream variable)

```
in >> format >> number;
format.erase(format.length() - 1);
```

However, when reading from the test data below, the 4th number is read as **23.489999999999998** (as shown in debugging and printing). How can I prevent this?

```
&&&&&&, 456
&&&&&&,&, 1000000
$&&&&.&&, 123.38
&&&.&&&, 23.49
&&&.&&&, 23.4999
&&&E, 45
```

Comment: That's not wrong reading. That's right reading, and possibly wrong printing it out afterwards. (It is correct printing, but apparently not what you want. If you want to always print a floating point value *exactly* as you read it, you'll have to just use a string.)

Comment: That's not "wrong".

Comment: Show the code that are you using for debugging and printing. Specify what is the input, and what is your desired output

Comment: I think it is not a duplicate, He is asking how to prevent, not why that happens

Comment: @Rama understanding why it happens is the first (and a very important/necessary) step in preventing it.

Comment: @JesperJuhl that's true! Just I'm not agree with the "exact" duplicate flag

Answer (score 1):

Floating point values do not have infinite precission - they are approximations.

Your value is being read just fine and converted to the nearest possible approximation that can be stored in a `double`.

You should spend some time reading [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: In conclusion: don't use C++, don't use floating point, use C#'s decimal.